# Can Sublime text 2 set separate word_separators config for each file type?

Tags: sublimetext2

I know how to set the global word_separators, but I want set `_` as a word_separators for html file type but not affect other file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file in Sublime with JSON syntax and the following contents:

```js
{
    "word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?_"
}
```

Save the file in `Packages/User` as `HTML.sublime-settings`, and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks for your guide, but only Sublime text 2 Can set underscore as a word separator.

Comment: @jfxiao I'm not sure what you're getting at. Are you asking if you can do the same thing in Sublime Text 3? The answer is yes.